# Python C Extension- binary build wheel error - is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python-2.7, python-c-extension, python-wheel

Recently a custom python extension started giving this error after getting built by wheel as binary - python setup.py  bdist_wheel

Seems that the ABI tag,is now getting added in new version of wheel see [.27](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel)
version details.

Quick test proved this was the problem; Note the [ABI](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/) tag cp27m in first and changing it to none in file name worked

```
alex-VirtualBox tmp # pip install xxxxx-1.0.1+ddd-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl
xxxxx-1.0.1%2Bddd-cp27-cp27m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

alex-VirtualBox tmp # pip install xxxxx-1.0.1+ddd-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl 
Unpacking ./xxxxx-1.0.1+ddd-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: xxxxx
Successfully installed xxxxx
Cleaning up...
```

How to make the disutils set the ABI tag to None in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

One way seems to be to set the ABI tag in setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from os import path

C_EXT_SOURCE_DIR = "c-module/src/"
SOURCE_FILES = ["module_v1.c", "x2.c"]

xy_extension = Extension("module_v1",

sources=[C_EXT_SOURCE_DIR + path for path in SOURCE_FILES],abi="none")
setup(name='xxx',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=["test"]),
      version="1.0.1",
      description='xxx',
      author='xxx',
      ext_modules=[xy_extension],
      include_package_data=True
      )
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way, though it is mentioned partly here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3149/

Comment: this is not implemented and not recognized option warning is emitted, so no use of this.

Answer (score 0):

With new wheel this ABI tag is added; If you are getting the error in Python 2.7, maybe your setup-tools version is old

```
easy_install --version
setuptools 5.7
```

Upgrade to [latest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) setup-tools version using easy-install

If you need to specify the ABI tag explicitly in your C-Extension module, this [link](http://pythonextensionpatterns.readthedocs.org/en/latest/debugging/debug_python.html) might help